# Delete duplicates with multiple grouping conditions

Tags: r

I want to delete duplicates with multiple grouping conditions but always get way less results than expected.

The dataframe compares two companies per year. Like this:

| year | c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | a | b |
| 2000 | a | c |
| 2000 | a | d |
| 2001 | a | b |
| 2001 | b | d |
| 2001 | a | c |

For every c1 I want to look at c2 and delete rows which are in the previous year.
I found a similar problem but with just one c. Here are some of my tries so far:

```
df<- df%>%
  group_by(c1,c2) %>%
  mutate(dup = n() > 1) %>%
  group_split() %>%
  map_dfr(~ if(unique(.x$dup) & (.x$year[2] - .x$year[1]) == 1) {
    .x %>% slice_head(n = 1)
  } else {
    .x
  }) %>%
  select(-dup) %>%
  arrange(year)
```

```
df<- sqldf("select a.*
  from df a
  left join df b on b.c1=a.c1 and b.c2 = a.c2 and b.year = a.year - 1
  where  b.year is null")
```

The desired output for the example would be:

| year | c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | a | b |
| 2000 | a | c |
| 2000 | a | d |
| 2001 | b | d |

Comment: what if there is one more row say, `2002-a-d`

Comment: should be included again since 2001 has no a d combination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to check duplicate in the previous year only.  So showing it to you on a **modified sample**

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = 'year   c1  c2
2000    a   b
2000    a   c
2000    a   d
2001    a   b
2001    b   d
2001    a   c
2002  a d')

df %>%
  filter(map2_lgl(df$year, paste(df$c1, df$c2), ~ !paste(.x -1, .y) %in% paste(df$year, df$c1, df$c2)))
#>   year c1 c2
#> 1 2000  a  b
#> 2 2000  a  c
#> 3 2000  a  d
#> 4 2001  b  d
#> 5 2002  a  d
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Check it now please.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other solutions won't work because I think they ignore the fact that you will probably have many years and want to eliminate duplicates from only the prior.

Here is something fairly simple. You could do this in some `map` function or whatnot, but sometimes a simple loop does just fine. For each year of data, use `anti_join()` to return only those values from the current year which are not in the prior year. Then just restack the data.

```r
df_split <- df %>% 
  group_split(year)

for (this_year in 2:length(df_split)) {
  
  df_split[[this_year]] <- df_split[[this_year]] %>% 
    anti_join(df_split[[this_year - 1]], by = c("c1", "c2"))
  
}

bind_rows(df_split)
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#    year c1    c2   
#   <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1  2000 a     b    
# 2  2000 a     c    
# 3  2000 a     d    
# 4  2001 b     d
```

**Edit**

Another approach is to add a dummy column for the prior year and just use an `anti_join()` with that. This is probably what I would do.

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(prior_year = year - 1) %>% 
  anti_join(df, by = c(prior_year = "year", "c1", "c2")) %>% 
  select(-prior_year)
```

Comment: yes, a good one upvoted!  I also assumed/understood that duplicates have to filtered/checked from previous year only

Comment: yeah, i saw. yours works as well and inspired an edit i am about to make. I think you can just do a very simple anti_join and be done with it!

Comment: yeah!  Superb idea!  I wish I could upvote twice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  filter(pmap_int(list(df$c1, df$c2, df$year), ~ df %>%
                    filter(year %in% c(..3, ..3 - 1)) %>%
                    rowwise() %>%
                    mutate(output = all(c(..1, ..2) %in% c_across(c1:c2))) %>%
                    pull(output) %>% sum) < 2)

# AnilGoyal's modified data set
  year c1 c2
1 2000  a  b
2 2000  a  c
3 2000  a  d
4 2001  b  d
5 2002  a  d
```

Answer (score 0):

this will only keep the data u want.
The `data`is your data frame.

`data[!duplicated(data[,2:3]),]`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty simple with base `duplicated` using the fromLast option to get the last rather than the first entry. (It does assum the ordering by year.

```
dat[!duplicated(dat[2:3], fromLast=TRUE), ] # negate logical vector in i-position
  year c1 c2
3 2000  a  d
4 2001  a  b
5 2001  b  d
6 2001  a  c
```

I do get a different result than you said was expected so maybe I misunderstood the specifications?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that you indeed wanted to keep your *last* year, as stated in the question, but contrary to your example table, you could simply use slice:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(year=c("2000","2000","2000","2001","2001","2001"),
                c1 = c("a","a","a","a","b","a"),c2=c("b","c","d","b","d","c"))
df  %>% group_by(c1,c2) %>%
  slice_tail() %>%arrange(year,c1,c2)
```

Use slice_head(), if you wanted the *first* year.
Here is the documentation: [slice](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html)